# ApexCharts bars are too thin on rangeBar type

Tags: javascript, charts, apexcharts

So, we rely on ApexCharts v3.37.2 to render list of workers currently assigned to various projects. We use the rangeBar type to represent the data.

The problem is when we add more than a dozen items to the Y axis, the bars on the main area get so thin that they don't look easily detectable.

Is there any way that we can have a minimum thickness for bars without making them overlap or hide behind each other? We used stroke but were not happy with results due to overlapping bars. Some of them were completely hidden.

Also, is there a smart way of assigning proportionate height to each entry/item on the Y axis, so that if one project has more bars, it will get more space inside the viewport and vice-versa?

In short, how best to render a range bar that is over populated with bars across 1-6 months or so?

Here is an example of what we have, and thank you for your help.

[image: chart]